# Mongo index selection differs between aggregate and find and between databases

Tags: mongodb

This question is two part, but both relate to index selection heuristics.

Context: We have around 4000 databases of identical collection, document and index structure (this last one in particular has been confirmed repeatedly), spread across ~40 clusters - this isn't particularly important beyond the fact that it identifies the unusual behaviour we're seeing.

In each of these databases, we have a `tasks` collection - with a number of indexes defined. In particular:

```
{ ignored: 1 }
{ assignment_strategy: 1, due_date: 1 }
```

We have an aggregation:

```
[
{ $match: { 
   ignored: false,
   due_date: { $exists: true, $ne: null },
   assignment_strategy: "whatever",
   complete: false,
   assignment_attempted: false
} },
{ $group: {
  _id: "$label",
  count: { $sum: 1 }
} }
]
```

Two problems:

1. In most of the databases, this correctly chooses the index `{ assignment_strategy: 1, due_date: 1 }`. Unfortunately, in some of them it uses `{ ignored: 1 }`
2. In the databases that choose the wrong index for aggregation - if I switch to a find (using the `$match` as the selector) it chooses the correct index

The `{ ignored: 1 }` index should be unequivocally wrong in this case - `ignored: false` is usually the majority of tasks (ignored ~= deleted). In one case, of the ~857k documents the `{ ignored: 1 }` index returns ~544k for doc scan - the query takes 11 seconds. Compared with the correct index which filters to ~90k (still not ideal) but only takes ~600ms.

The databases in question are all hosted by Atlas - there seems to be no correlation between which clusters have databases which select the wrong index - my assumption is it's entirely based on the distribution of documents within the collection. We're on mongo 6.

My questions:

1. where can I read more about the mongo index selection heuristic? I'm familiar with most of the output of explain, but can't fathom why mongo would choose an index that even explain recognises is terrible (both on examined:returned ratio and time)
2. why would the index selection change between find and aggregate?

Regarding question (2) I'm wondering if this is because the group stage makes it look like the returned docs is smaller than it is (the $group returns only a handful of docs, but the $match matches to ~2500) but I'd hope mongo is smarter than this. I tried changing the $group stage to make the `_id: "all"` - interestingly this did two things:

1. it changed the structure of the explain result - it no longer had a `.queryPlanner` entry (it had `stages` instead).
2. it used the correct index.

We're going to make the "correct" index even more selective (to get that 90k down closer to the 2k) but I'm not convinced that a more selective index will help, given that mongo is insisting on choosing the wrong index currently.